# python argparse extra args

Tags: python, arguments, argparse

i would like to get extra args using `argparse` but without known what are they. 
for example, in `maven` we can add parameters in the form:
`-Dmaven.test.skip=true` or `-Dcmd=compiler:compile`

i would like to get the same thing in python using `argparse`, and get some kind of `dict` with all the args..

i know i can use:

```
aparser.parse_known_args()
```

but then i need to parse me extra args (remove the `-D` and split by `=`). Was wondering if there is something out of the box?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
parser.add_argument('-D', action='append', default=[])
```

which will turn arguments

```
-Dfoo -Dbar=baz
```

into

```
>>> args.D
['foo', 'bar=baz']
```

And no `-D` arguments will mean that `args.D` will return an empty list.

---

If you want them as a dictionary right there, you can have a custom action:

```
def ensure_value(namespace, dest, default):
    stored = getattr(namespace, dest, None)
    if stored is None:
        return value
    return stored


class store_dict(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        vals = dict(ensure_value(namespace, self.dest, {}))
        k, _, v = values.partition('=')
        vals[k] = v
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, vals)


parser.add_argument('-D', default={}, action=store_dict)
```

which, given `-Dfoo -Dbar=baz` will result in

```
>>> args.D
{'bar': 'baz', 'foo': ''}
```

which is *slightly* more verbose than using the `action='append'` with

```
>>> as_dict = dict(i.partition('=')[::2] for i in args.D)
```

Comment: it will mean i need to split by `=` by it will do. Thanks !