# Python argparse dict arg

Tags: python, dictionary, argparse

I want to receive a `dict(str -> str)` argument from the command line. Does `argparse.ArgumentParser` provide it? Or any other library?

For the command line:

```
program.py --dict d --key key1 --value val1 --key key2 --value val2
```

I expect the following dictionary:

```
d = {"key1": "val1", "key2": "val2"}
```

Comment: Are you doing argument parsing or what? Collecting it to a dict doesn't seem really meaningful.

Comment: @skyline75489. Yes. I parsing the **d** argument. Why lists can be arguments, and dictionaries can not..

Comment: Arguments can be very complex. It can be optional or required, positional or non-positional, need-value or do-not-need-value. I'm thinking adding `dict` support would make things even more complicated.

Comment: How about [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29335145/python-argparse-extra-args/29335524#29335524)?

Comment: wouldn't it be better as `program.py --opt1 k1=v1,k2=v2,k3=v3`?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala This is good. Kind of similar to what I did in the answer below.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala - I like that approach.  I wish it would've worked for my use case when I had to do essentially the same thing as the OP is trying to do here.

Comment: Another option is to input the values as a (quoted) JSON string.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Here's another solution using a **custom action**, if you want to specify dict key pairs together comma-separated --

```
import argparse
import sys
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='parse key pairs into a dictionary')

class StoreDictKeyPair(argparse.Action):
     def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
         my_dict = {}
         for kv in values.split(","):
             k,v = kv.split("=")
             my_dict[k] = v
         setattr(namespace, self.dest, my_dict)

parser.add_argument("--key_pairs", dest="my_dict", action=StoreDictKeyPair, metavar="KEY1=VAL1,KEY2=VAL2...")

args = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
print args
```

Running:

```
python parse_kv.py --key_pairs 1=2,a=bbb,c=4 --key_pairs test=7,foo=bar
```

Output:

```
Namespace(my_dict={'1': '2', 'a': 'bbb', 'c': '4', 'test': '7', 'foo': 'bar'})
```

If you want to use **nargs** instead of comma-separated values in string:

```
class StoreDictKeyPair(argparse.Action):
     def __init__(self, option_strings, dest, nargs=None, **kwargs):
         self._nargs = nargs
         super(StoreDictKeyPair, self).__init__(option_strings, dest, nargs=nargs, **kwargs)
     def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
         my_dict = {}
         print "values: {}".format(values)
         for kv in values:
             k,v = kv.split("=")
             my_dict[k] = v
         setattr(namespace, self.dest, my_dict)

parser.add_argument("--key_pairs", dest="my_dict", action=StoreDictKeyPair, nargs="+", metavar="KEY=VAL")

args = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
print args
```

Running

```
python arg_test4.py --key_pairs 1=2 a=bbb c=4 test=7 foo=bar
```

Outputs:

```
values: ['1=2', 'a=bbb', 'c=4', 'test=7', 'foo=bar']
Namespace(my_dict={'1': '2', 'a': 'bbb', 'c': '4', 'test': '7', 'foo': 'bar'})
```

Comment: This is definitely the best answer

Comment: Undervalued answer. Alas, I've already given this all the love I have to give.

Comment: Great answer (already upvoted) but this doesn't parse boolean strings as boolean or other data types (list, dict) passed as strings. Need to eval the value. Just a heads up !

Comment: I used `my_dict[k] = ast.literal_eval(v)` to implement the type cast

Comment: Under the `__call__` method I had to use `my_dict = getattr(namespace, self.dest, {})` to get this to work after I switched to using subparsers, and tyvm, this is great

Answer (score 23):

I would use something like this:

```
p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument("--keyvalue", action='append',
               type=lambda kv: kv.split("="), dest='keyvalues')

args = p.parse_args("--keyvalue foo=6 --keyvalue bar=baz".split())
d = dict(args.keyvalues)
```

You could create a custom action which would "append" a parsed key-value pair directly into a dictionary, rather than simply accumulating a list of `(key, value)` tuples. (Which I see is what skyline75489 did; my answer differs in using a single `--keyvalue` option with a custom type instead of separate `--key` and `--value` options to specify pairs.)

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is the best.

Comment: I would recommend using `kv.split("=", 1)` to allow `=` in the value and ensure that you have at most 2 elements.

Comment: Also: `if any(len(kv) < 2 for kv in args.keyvalues): raise ValueError('Values must be given in the form "KEY=VALUE"')`

Answer (score 10):

just another easy way:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--key1')
parser.add_argument('--key2')
args = parser.parse_args()
my_dict = args.__dict__
```

Comment: No, I don't want to convert agruments into dictionary. It can be easily done: `arguments = vars(parser.parse_args())`. Please reread question with example

Comment: It's generally not a great practice to access the `__dict__` property of a class you don't control as it can contain metadata you aren't expecting.

Answer (score 5):

use vars

```
d = vars(parser.parse_args())
```

Comment: Thank you for the contribution. But your code doesn't solve the problem. It just convert all passed arguments into dictionary, but code should also work with unknown dynamic keys.

Answer (score 3):

Python receives arguments in the form of an array `argv`. You can use this to create the dictionary in the program itself.

```
import sys
my_dict = {}
for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
    key, val=arg.split(':')[0], arg.split(':')[1]
    my_dict[key]=val

print my_dict
```

For command line:

```
python program.py key1:val1 key2:val2 key3:val3
```

Output:

```
my_dict = {'key3': 'val3', 'key2': 'val2', 'key1': 'val1'}
```

> Note: args will be in string, so you will have to convert them to store numeric values.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I think your solution is ok, but it is little dirty.
1. keys and values can't contains ':'
2. too hard to control the order of multiple arguments

Comment: what I gave is not the only solution, the point is you have a list of arguments - ['key1', 'val1', 'key2', 'val2', 'key3', 'val3'], so can obtain dict with any logic, eg: every even element (say pos 'i') is the key and value for it will be at pos (i+1), so just run the loop with a step size of 2 and store the dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

Python one-line argparse dictionary arguments [argparse_dictionary.py](https://gist.github.com/miszellek/281446a74a169d2da95fd4a6c80e4211)

```
# $ python argparse_dictionary.py --arg_dict=1=11,2=22;3=33 --arg_dict=a=,b,c=cc,=dd,=ee=,
# Namespace(arg_dict={'1': '11', '2': '22', '3': '33', 'a': '', 'c': 'cc', '': 'dd'})

import argparse

arg_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
arg_parser.add_argument(
    '--arg_dict',
    action=type(
        '', (argparse.Action, ),
        dict(__call__=lambda self, parser, namespace, values, option_string: getattr(
            namespace, self.dest).update(
                dict([
                    v.split('=') for v in values.replace(';', ',').split(',')
                    if len(v.split('=')) == 2
                ])))),
    default={},
    metavar='KEY1=VAL1,KEY2=VAL2;KEY3=VAL3...',
)
print(arg_parser.parse_args())
```

Comment: Good point, but I'm sorry - it is non-readable code. Use pep8 please.

Answer (score 0):

A straight forward way of parsing an input like:

```
program.py --dict d --key key1 --value val1 --key key2 --value val2
```

is:

```
parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--dict')
parser.add_argument('--key', action='append')
parser.add_argument('--value', action='append')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

which should produce (if my mental parser is correct)

```
args = Namespace(dict='d', key=['key1','key2'], value=['value1','value2'])
```

You should be able construct a dictionary from that with:

```
adict = {k:v for k, v in zip(args.key, args.value)}
```

Using `args.dict` to assign this to a variable with that name requires some un-python trickery.  The best would be to create a element in another dictionary with this name.

```
another_dict = {args.dict: adict}
```

This solution doesn't perform much error checking.  For example, it doesn't make sure that there are the same number of keys and values.  It also wouldn't let you create multiple dictionaries (i.e. repeated `--dict` arguments).  It doesn't require any special order.  `--dict` could occur after a `--key key1` pair.  Several `--value` arguments could be together.

Tying the `key=value` together as `chepner` does gets around a number of those problems.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution in Python 3.6 if you're simply trying to convert argparse input to a dictionary. An example is as follows:

```
import argparse 

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-i', '--input', help='the path to the input file')
parser.add_argument('-o', '--output', help='the path to the output file')
args = parser.parse_args()

arguments = dict(args._get_kwargs())

for k, v in arguments.items():
    print(k, v)
```

Given command line input such as `python3 script_name.py --input 'input.txt' --output 'output.txt'` the code would output to terminal:

```
input input.txt
output output.txt
```

Comment: No, I don't want to convert agruments into dictionary. It can be easily done without hack with hidden field: `arguments = vars(parser.parse_args())`. Please reread question with example.

Comment: `arguments = vars(parser.parse_args())` that is soooo often what you want in this situation.

Answer (score -1):

As for the current libraries like [argparse](http://pymotw.com/2/argparse/), [docopt](http://docopt.org/) and [click](http://docopt.org/), none of them support using `dict` args. The best solution I can think of is to make a custom `argparse.Action` to support it youself:

```
import argparse

class MyAction(argparse.Action):
    def __init__(self, option_strings, dest, nargs=None, **kwargs):
        super(MyAction, self).__init__(option_strings, dest, nargs, **kwargs)

    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        print '%r %r %r' % (namespace, values, option_string)
        value_dict = {}
        values.reverse()
        while len(values) > 0:
            v = eval(values.pop()).lstrip('--') # This is like crazy hack, I know.
            k = eval(values.pop())
            value_dict[k] = v

        setattr(namespace, self.dest, value_dict)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-d', action=MyAction, nargs='*')
args = parser.parse_args('-d "--key" "key1" "--value" "val1" "--key" "key2" "--value" "val2"'.split())

print(args)
```