# Python3 +var=value arguments with Argparse

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line, argparse

I have a Python 3 program that uses the argparse module to collect command line arguments, and I would like to add a feature to my program so that arguments may be taken which set an arbitrary internal variable to a value at runtime.

For example: `./program.py --regular-option +myvar=apples +othervar=oranges`

Is this something that argparse can handle? Otherwise, how do I prevent argparse from thinking a nonexistent option has been passed while I manually extract these options from sys.argv?

Comment: `argparse` does not naturally handle arbitrary key:value pairs.  But we have discussed, in previous questions, possible solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34384865/using-a-variable-keyword-for-an-optional-argument-name-with-python-argparse

Comment: Thank you, the keywords I was searching with didn't find that.

Comment: I decided to handle the problem by processing and removing arguments starting with a "+" from sys.argv before invoking Argparse.